# Pentaho 6: CDE and OLAP Selector wizard

Tags: pentaho, business-intelligence, olap, pentaho-cde, saiku

I'am trying to create a Dashboard in Pentaho 6 with CDE. I'm follwing this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nq86J5t5c18).

I already have a Cube and I've been using it on other tools like "Saiku", "New Openl Analysis report" and "Pivot4j". The problem occurs on **CDE** with the **OLAP Selector wizard**. When I select my cube on this Wizard the dimensions and measures do not shows up.

I already checked the log file while doing this and no message was written there.

Screen shot of the wizard [wizard screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnXaN.png)

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot?

Comment: I put a link to the OLAP Wizard.

Comment: Saiku screen shot .
http://i.stack.imgur.com/iUx0t.png

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**
The problem was that my mondrian schema had these chars "/", ":", "(" and ")". I only discovered this by inspecting the javascript code while the datasource have been selected.